# Load a Config file on an Android app using Appium with Java

Tags: java, android, appium

I have been searching for a long time to find a way to import a config file on an Android app using Appium with Java. I am still learning on this and I hope that I find some help here.

Here is the case:

I have an android app that I started testing but before that I have to import a configuration file into this app in order to become active.

public class sipphone extends base {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver=capabilities();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);



   File configImport= new File("src"); 
   File file= new File(configImport, "testconfig.config");


    driver.findElementById("android:id/button1").click();
    driver.findElementById("android:id/btn_later").click();


try{
```

//import file from src directory

```
}

catch (Exception e) { 

    return;

}
```

}
}

How can I load the file inside the try block and then into the Android App?

Answer (score 1):

Please check

https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/android/PushesFiles.html#pushFile

Search on http://discuss.appium.io/ or https://github.com/appium/appium on how to use it